# In my Canvas app, how would I get where the user just came from?

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-canvas

Basically, when a user clicks a link to my facebook canvas app page, how can I get the page on which that link was clicked using Javascript or MVC 3?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript: document.referrer

Comment: Or Request.UrlReferrer in .Net

Comment: That would just return the facebook page wouldn't it since the iframe is essentially a new document right?